# How to force modules recompilation in multimodule SpringBoot maven project?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, maven-3, maven-module

There is a Maven project with two modules with this structure.

```
project
    moduleA
       pom.xml   // library 

    moduleB
       pom.xml   // SpringBoot application

    pom.xml      // parent aggregator
```

Module B depends on A.

When executing command `mvn spring-boot:run -pl moduleB` (from `project` folder) Maven takes compiled package `moduleA.jar` **from local repository** and fails if it is absent there.

Please, help me to find a way of forcing **usage of the latest compiled** `moduleA` version every time the `moduleB` application starts.

In perfect case I would like to avoid  `mvn install` step, just inducing `mvn compile` (if code changed) or reusing a compiled `moduleA`; but it also works if somehow application could be started with the latest compiled version of all code in the multimodular project.

Comment: Please show your pom files... Apart from that where are you starting your command (which location?)

Comment: Would'nt an -am (also make) force do it if the modules are interdependent . From the sub-project mvn clean compile install -am

Comment: First using `clean compile install` shows that you haven't understood the life cycle. `mvn clean install` is sufficient.. Furthermore I would suggest to build from root location (project/ directory instead) because you have a dependency to moduleA... this would mean you can just use `mvn clean package` instead... running spring boot app is just `java -jar xyz.jar` ...